# Prevent sign-ups of existing usernames with uppercase

Tags: meteor

how to prevent duplicate username on signup page?  Any username can be duplicated by changing 1 letter to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both usernames (form and database) to lowercase before comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Accounts.validateNewUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser).  This gets called with a user object, you can make the checks there, including comparing case-insensitive usernames to your existing user-base.  Then return false if a user already exists, stopping the registration process.